# What quantity does a line integral represent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around line integrals, Green's theorem, and vector fields and I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what a line integral represents geometrically.

Is it basically the arc length of a curve, for a scalar field?

And then when you bring the concept into a vector field, then what does it represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if the integrand is a function of point mass, then the line integral over a curve will give you the mass of that curve. Also, when you integrate over a vector field, it physically represents the work done by the field on a particle that moves along a path.

A line integral can help you to calculate the area of a fence or curtain that's below the curve, in $\mathbb R^3.$

Rodolfo Llinás says that we learn when we put things into context. I believe him, and these interpretations of line integrals are very classical.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.  So in multivariable calculus, if the curve C for the line integral is oriented on the xy plane, the integrand is the z=f(x,y) function?  And in that scenario, that gives the area of the surface created by the space curve bounded by z=lower limit and z=f(x,y)?

Comment: That's one interpretation as well. You're correct. However the integral is just the sum of things. We just want to give it an interpretation, and a very good one is the area of a wall that goes from $z=f(x,y)$ to $z=0$.

Comment: Also, in regard to the line integral for a vector field, does that represent anything strictly in mathematical terms?

Comment: It depends always on the vector field... It may be a force field, a velocity field...

Comment: So are vector fields strictly used in physics?  Is it just the sum of the magnitudes of every applicable vector in the vector field applied to a point as the point travels along path C?

Comment: As raw as it might look, yes, it's just the sum of dot products, not even as a point travelling, the points are already there. You just go with your parametrization of the path $C$ and sum things. It gives the sensation that you are travelling though.

Comment: Vector fields come out from differential equations, for example... With these vector fields you know how the solutions of a differential equation behave

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, this answered my questions perfectly.

Comment: Also I'm a physics student, so have little experience with vector fields outside from physics. But sure, they're widely used in the study of differential equations.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two worthwhile interpretations of a line integral in two-dimensions.

First, $\int_C (\vec{F} \cdot T)ds = \int_C Pdx+Qdy$ measures the work or circulation of the vector field along the oriented curve $C$. This integral is largest when the vector field aligns itself along the **tangent** direction of $C$. As this relates to Green's Theorem we obtain the usual form of Green's Theorem which is identified with the $z$-component of the curl a bit later in the course. For $C = \partial R$
$$ \int_{\partial R} (\vec{F} \cdot T)ds = \iint_R (\nabla \times \vec{F})_z dA $$

Second, $\int_C (\vec{F} \cdot n)ds = \int_C Pdy-Qdx$ measures the flux of the vector field emitted through the oriented curve $C$. This integral is largest when the vector field aligns itself along the **normal** direction of $C$. As this relates to Green's Theorem we obtain the so-called **divergence**-form of Green's Theorem which is related to the Divergence Theorem in due course.
$$ \int_{\partial R} (\vec{F} \cdot n)ds = \iint_R (\nabla \cdot \vec{F}) dA $$

If you want to read more, one source would be pages 357-367 of [my multivariable calculus notes](http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIf2014.pdf) which were heavily influenced by Taylor's excellent calculus text.

Comment: to be clear, I don't think the question "what does the line integral mean geometrically?" is the correct question. It has some meaning, but, it is in a higher dimensional context where the vector field and curve both appear as objects. Otherwise, in the three dimensional context, the line-integral says something about the pair $(C, \vec{F})$ and how they relate.

Comment: Thanks James.  Your notes are a bit more expansive than what I'm used to, my feeble mind is having some difficulty reading them (for example, I don't know what CCW means).  Our class is following Larson's Early Transcendental Functions calculus book.

Comment: @Irongrave Sorry about that, CCW = Counter-Clock-Wise